# AMD Driver to a laptop error

Tags: drivers, radeon

I have a Dell Inspiron N5110 with Radeon HD 7400M.

I'm trying to installing the driver, but I get this error:

```
   ERROR: Please install the required pre-requisites before proceeding with AMD Catalyst installation. Please check file usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for more details.
    Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.gt8xH5
```

The log file says:

```
   NOTE: If your system has logged the missing packages required for installation, install them in the order as per the log file to resolve package-dependency issues.
    fglrx installation requires that the system has kernel headers.  /lib/modules/4.4.0-47-lowlatency/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
    Install kernel headers using the command apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-47-lowlatency.
```

When I try to install the linux headers:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-47-lowlatency
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
linux-headers-4.4.0-47-lowlatency is already the newest version (4.4.0-47.68).
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 7 não atualizados.
```

I dont know what to do from now. Can someone help me, please?
I've downloaded lot of drivers from AMD, but none results.

Thanks!

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you on?

Comment: I use the version 16.04

Comment: Then you cannot install the fglrx driver. You must use the open-source drivers, or select whatever driver might be available from "Additional Drivers".

Comment: Can you send me the links to the open-source drivers? I don't know it.